# How to make a generic procedure pointer in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am a low level Fortran programmer. I am trying to make subroutines as generic as possible and I wonder if I can send an information of which subroutine another subroutine should acces from a given information in the main program. For instance, if I have:

```
program main
use test
implicit none
real(8) X
end program main
```

And:

```
module test

contains

subroutine A (X)
real(8) X
X = 2*X
end subroutine A

subroutine B (X)
real(8) X
X = 3*X
end subroutine B

end module test
```

I would like to, given the subroutine name 'A' or 'B' in the main program, transfer this to a third subroutine `C` inside the module test, which in turn would make some calculations and use the transferred name to choose between `A` and `B` in its calculations.

I know if I build the calculations of that subroutine `C` inside the main program, I can use a procedure pointer to access either `A` or `B` subroutines. However, I need to have the subroutine `C`. So I guess I will have a subroutine `C` with built in procedure pointer and it will take the name given in the main program as an argument. But I do not know how to do that. Neither if it is possible. If it is not, is there any other way? I do not know, maybe the subroutine `C` reading a txt file associating the read name to the procedure pointer. But, how?

Thank you, in advance!

Comment: You can read about _dummy procedures_, if I understand correctly what you want

Comment: Real(8) is so ugly and there is even no need for it in such a simple example.

Comment: Generic in which sense? I don't get what is your aim. Could you illustrate it by code instead of words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you want is this: you first define subroutines `A` and `B`

```
module ab_m
  implicit none
contains

  subroutine A(X)
    real, intent(inout) :: X
    X = 2 * X
  end subroutine A

  subroutine B(X)
    real, intent(inout) :: X
    X = 3 * X
  end subroutine B

end module ab_m
```

Then subroutine `C` uses a dummy procedure, specified by an interface,

```
module c_m
  implicit none
contains

  subroutine C(sub,y)

    interface
       subroutine sub(p)
         implicit none
         real, intent(inout) :: p
       end subroutine sub
    end interface

    real, intent(inout) :: y
    y = y + 1
    call sub(y)

  end subroutine C

end module c_m
```

and the main program chooses what procedure to use in `C`:

```
program p

  use ab_m 
  use c_m
  implicit none
  real :: z(2)

  z = 1.0
  call C(B, z(1))        
  call C(A, z(2))
  write(*,*) z     ! writes 6.0, 4.0 [ (1+1)*3, (1+1)*2) ]

end program p
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! That is exactly what I am needing!